# VBA macro excel export colums with first row header present data

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns

How can I export all the columns with data present (header) in the first row?

In this example image, I would like to export only the column with **"FOO"** present:

[image]

**this is my code;**

```
Sub Worksheets_to_txt() 

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim relativePath As String
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult

    relativePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    answer = MsgBox("Export in TXT?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")    
    If answer = vbYes Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        ws.Select
        ws.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        relativePath & "\" & ws.Name & ".txt", _
        FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    Next
     End If

End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Delete those columns before exporting and do not sabe changes in source

Comment: You can use code You already prepared, but before that, create piece of code with a check of 1 row for FOO, and if it is not found -> delete such column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, replace this part of your code:

```
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        ws.Select
        ws.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        relativePath & "\" & ws.Name & ".txt", _
        FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    Next
```

with this one:

```
   Dim rngDel As Range, lastCol As Long, wsNew As Worksheet, HDRow As Long, i As Long
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     if ws.Range("A1").value <> "" then
        ws.Copy
        Set wsNew = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        'search for the header row:
        For i = 1 To 100
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsNew.rows(i)) > 0 Then
                HDRow = i: Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        lastCol = wsNew.cells(HDRow, wsNew.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'place all cells from the first row, without headers, in a Union range
        For i = 1 To lastCol
            If wsNew.cells(HDRow, i).value = "" Then
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = wsNew.cells(HDRow, i)
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, wsNew.cells(HDRow, i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        'delete the columns without header, if any:
        If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireColumn.Delete
        Set rngDel = Nothing 'preparing the range for the next sheet use
        ActiveWorkbook.saveas fileName:= _
                relativePath & "\" & ws.Name & ".txt", _
                FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

It places the first row cells without a header in a range and delete this range entire columns at once, before saving the workbook.

Comment: Thank you @FaneDuru, but it's not work... It's export all columns also with no data in first rows and delete the first column always

Comment: @ pasaico Ups... I was not atentive enough. I will adapt it in a glance. Adapted. But it will work as it should **only if the headers exist on the first  row**, as we could see in your picture. If not (in all of them) you should state that, give some more pieces of information and I will adapt the code to preliminarily search for the headers row...

Comment: @pasaico Looking to "with no data in first rows", it is clear that you did not show us all the truth... :) **I adapted the code to firstly determine the headers row**. But it will work **only if no any data exists on the rows above the one with headers**...

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself badly, I meant "data present in the first row"
I have test in my real multisheet excel, but after first two sheets i receive "Error run-time 424: required object" i click on debug and highlighted in yellow "rngDel.EntireColumn.Delete" in the line:  If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireColumn.Delete

Comment: @pasaico I should modify a little the code. When such a range is built it remains in Excel memory, even if the workbook containing it is already closed. For the next sheet the actual code will try using the existing range. I must set it as Nothing. I will adapt now the code. Adapted. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: is possibile add: "if cell a1 is empty do not export the current sheet" ?

Comment: @pasaico yes, not so complicated. I will adapt it.

Comment: @pasaico Adapted...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this problem. Instead of removing columns, I'm collecting them in `ExportRange` and copy it to new file.

```
Option Explicit

' Info: Method loops over all worksheets in current Workbook
' and looks for headers with name "Foo". Every column with
' Foo name is exported to the text file with the name of
' that worksheet.

Public Sub Export()

    Dim DataSource As Worksheet
    For Each DataSource In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If DataSource.Range("A1").Value = vbNullString Then
            GoTo NextItem
        End If
    
        Dim Header As Range: Set Header = DataSource.Rows(1).Find("Foo")
        If Header Is Nothing Then GoTo NextItem
        
        ' Understanding where Find method starts is essential
        ' to prevent looping back to the beginning using FindNext method.
        Dim StartAddress As String: StartAddress = Header.Address
        Dim ExportRange As Range
        Set ExportRange = GetColumnData(DataSource, Header.Columns)

        Set Header = DataSource.Rows(1).FindNext(Header)
        Do Until (Header Is Nothing) Or (Header.Address = StartAddress)
            Set ExportRange = Union(ExportRange, GetColumnData(DataSource, Header.Columns))
            Set Header = DataSource.Rows(1).FindNext(Header)
        Loop
        
        ExportRangeToText ExportRange, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & DataSource.Name
        
NextItem:
    Next DataSource

End Sub


Private Function GetColumnData(ByVal DataSource As Worksheet, ByVal DataColumn As Range) As Range
        
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = DataSource.Cells(DataSource.Rows.Count, DataColumn.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Set GetColumnData = DataColumn.Resize(LastRow, 1)
    
End Function


Private Sub ExportRangeToText(ByVal Rng As Range, ByVal Filename As String)
    
    Dim Export As Workbook: Set Export = Application.Workbooks.Add
    Rng.Copy Export.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    Export.SaveAs Filename:=Filename & ".txt", _
                  FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
    Export.Close
    
End Sub
```